# How to update the upper_constraints.txt in devstack

Tags: libvirt, devstack

I'm hitting a problem with the upper_constraints file that devstack uses when installing (on CentOS).

This file is built at runtime? Does anyone know how I can edit this file? 
My problem is that the `upper_constraints.txt` sets `libvirt-python===3.10.0`. I've installed the latest version of `libvirt-python` which is 4.10.0. 
When I try to install 3.10.0, I'm hitting a wheel error.

If I can change the upper_constraints to go with the later version, I may be able to get around this issue but don't see where I can edit it (no point editing the file as it's dynamically built). 
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found two upper_constraints files. One is in the python site-packages. Updated both and that has fixed it (or at least moved me on to the next install error!)